# Losing precision while reading value from Excel

Tags: c#, excel, oledb

I need to read the values from Excel to DataSet using OleDb Connection.
Below is my code.

```
OleDbCommand excelCommand = new OleDbCommand(); 
OleDbDataAdapter    excelDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
string connectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;
Data Source=" + filelocation + @";Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0; IMEX=1;HDR=NO;""";
OleDbConnection excelConn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
excelConn.Open();
excelCommand = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]", excelConn);
excelDataAdapter.SelectCommand = excelCommand;
excelDataAdapter.Fill(ds);
```

While reading I am losing precision in my cell.

E.g.: 
Excel Cell has value -0.46256613817052

My DataSet has value -0.4625661

Most of my cells in the Excel sheet are of Number type.

How to solve this? Please help.

Comment: What type is excel column?

Comment: My Excel sheet has all type of columns. But majority of the columns has Number type.

Comment: I am glad you found the solution for your question Dinesh. Also as a reference you have used `IMEX=1` in your connection string though since you said you didn't.

Comment: Oh Sorry... I have tried without IMEX=1. But I missed to remove it from my posted connection string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this answer for [Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 rounding excel data?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7370ba54-ea3a-422d-a6e9-c13ee2bf1626/microsoftjetoledb40-rounding-excel-data?forum=adodotnetdataproviders)  , if you need to get exact values, you need to use visual studio tools for office.

I have solved the issue using [Excel Data Reader](http://exceldatareader.codeplex.com/)/